# Seeing of two strings are reflections of each other through recursion

Tags: java, string, recursion

My code is intended to take two strings and see if they are direct reflections of each other while ignoring case. For example, isReverse("abC", "cBA") should return true while isReverse("abde", "aedb") returns false.

I am having trouble determining if they are reflections. Why is the recursive case not working? I am new to recursive programming and this is quite a challenge.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String first = "abadcd";
        String second = "Dcdbua";
        System.out.println(isReverse(first, second));
    }

    public static boolean isReverse(String first, String second) {
        if (first.length() != second.length()) { // If string are not of equal length, impossible to be reverses
            return false;
        }

        String check1 = "" + first.charAt(first.length() - 1);
        String check2 = "" + second.charAt(0);
        if (check1.equalsIgnoreCase(check2)) { // gets the 1st char of first and last char of 2nd to see if it matches
            String temp1 = first.substring(1,first.length()-1); // shorten the string by escluding first char
            String temp2 = second.substring(0, second.length()-2); // shorten the string by last char
            isReverse(temp1, temp2);
        } 
        return true; // reaches here after goes through 
    }
```

Comment: There are a lot of issues in this function: (1) When does the recursion end? (2) When does the function return false? (3) Wrong usage of substring? (4) first and second swapped. Please fix at least a few of them yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code.

- You are missing the recursion. You need to return the call to isReverse in the isReverse method.
- You need a success termination (if both length are 0, the the strings are reverses of each others)
- The substrings indexes you use are not good
- You are inverting your strings between char comparaison and substrings
- You need to return false everywhere except in your stopping condition

  ```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      String first = "abadcd";
      String second = "Dcdbua";
      String third = "dcdabA";
      System.out.println("Should be false = " + isReverse(first, second));
      System.out.println("Should be true = " + isReverse(first, third));
    }

    public static boolean isReverse(String first, String second)
    {
      System.out.println("1=" + first + " / 2=" + second);
      if (first.length() != second.length())
      { // If string are not of equal length, impossible to be reverses
        return false;
      }

      // Stopping condition
      if (first.length() == 0 && second.length() == 0)
      {
        return true;
      }

      String check1 = "" + first.charAt(first.length() - 1);
      String check2 = "" + second.charAt(0);
      if (check1.equalsIgnoreCase(check2))
      { // gets the 1st char of first and last char of 2nd to see if it matches
        String temp1 = first.substring(0, first.length() - 1); // shorten the string by escluding first char
        String temp2 = second.substring(1, second.length()); // shorten the string by last char

        return isReverse(temp1, temp2);
      }
      return false; // reaches here after goes through
    }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems here.

1. You indexes for substring calls are not correct.
2. Your recursive call is incorrect: the point of calling isReverse recursively is to do
   something with its return value; you ignore it.
3. You do not have a "normal" termination case where you decide to return true (you do have a "return true", but see (2).